# making a b+tree concurrent (c)

Tags: c, data-structures, concurrency, b-tree

I am currently attempting to make a b+ tree concurrent.

So far the approach I had in mind as a starting point would be to iterate through the tree when inserting, locking each node (each node has its own lock) and unlocking once gotten the lock to the next node in the tree until a node which has a child who has the order of the b+ tree - 1 keys as anything under that node can be modified, after which all the necessary insert operations are ran and the node is unlocked.

This is obviously a very naive approach and doesnt offer much in the way of concurrency so I was wondering if there is a better way to go about this? Any inputs whatsoever would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You may get some interesting ideas by looking at [Palm Trees](https://runshenzhu.github.io/618-final/)

Comment: You need to overcome the problem that insertions and deletions can both affect multiple nodes.  It is therefore insufficient to lock only one node at a time when you are modifying the tree.

Comment: As a starting point, consider a read / write lock for the whole tree.  You can refine that into read / write locks for each node, where a mutation operation will end up taking out write locks on all the nodes along the path to the mutation point.  Ultimately, you could probably refine that to allow mutations to recognize when it is safe to eagerly release write locks earlier in the path to the mutation point.

Answer (score 7):

I have just finished one project on implementing a concurrent B+ tree. You can find some intuition from CMU 15-445 (Database Systems):

https://15445.courses.cs.cmu.edu/fall2018/slides/09-indexconcurrency.pdf (Slides)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6AiAR_giC6A&list=PLSE8ODhjZXja3hgmuwhf89qboV1kOxMx7&index=9 (Video)

One way to do this is called "latch crabbing". Basically, you need an RWLock for each node.

When you are searching for a leaf node, you add a Read(Search) or Write(Insert/Delete) lock on each of the node you visit. Once you discovered a node is "safe" (i.e. it won't split for insert, or it won't merge/redistribute with neighbors in delete), you can release the locks of its ancestors since you know the modification is limited to under this node. In this way, you are acquiring locks in the front and releasing locks on the back, walking like a crab, that's why it is called "latch crabbing" (I am misusing "latch" and "lock" here)

This can be hard to implement, good lock :)

Comment: awesome reference! That's a really good presentation, and the fact the video is freely available on YouTube is amazing.

Comment: @DarkZero What about trying to get a read-latches first for insertion and if we'll find later that the nodes are indeed pending for update, upgrade the read latches to write latches? Will it result in more concurrency for deletes/inserts?

Comment: I understand your statement as, when you are doing insertion, you reach a node A, if node A is full, then you want to grab a Read latch on it because you don't know whether it will actually split. But this is meaningless, because if one of the later nodes are not full, then node A is safe, so you can release its latch. Otherwise, every node in your path after A is full, it means A must split. Therefore, you don't have a chance to upgrade a latch. Please correct me if I'm wrong!